# Passing File Paths from Fragment to Activity and vice versa

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making my own app for practicing with Android programming. I'm making a Wizard composed by 3 fragments + a Summary Fragment and specifically in the third fragment the user has to take two pics and then pass it to the Summary (along with the previous data collected in the previous fragments). Where I'm not getting it is the part where I have to go back to the Main Activity and passing the images paths in order to call them back when I click to the button that make me go back to the Summary Fragment.

Here's the code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button personalData;
    protected String strUsername;
    private boolean isProfileReady;
    protected SharedPreferences loginData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        personalData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.data);
        personalData.setText("Profile Info");
        personalData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WizardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("profileReady", isProfileReady);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        loginData = getSharedPreferences("UserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = loginData.getString("Username", null);
        if (value == null) {
            welcome.setText("Welcome guest!");
            personalData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            welcome.setText("Welcome " + loginData.getString("Username", strUsername) + "!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            isProfileReady = true;
            personalData.setText("View Profile");
        }

    }
}
```

WizardActivity.java

```
public class WizardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SummaryFragment.Images {

    //region Variables
    Button go;
    WizardOne wizOne;
    WizardTwo wizTwo;
    WizardThree wizThree;
    SummaryFragment summaryFragment;
    Bitmap frontBitmap, backBitmap;
    SharedPreferences wizardPrefs;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    int currentPage = 1;

    public static final String FRONT_BITMAP_KEY = "frontBitmap", BACK_BITMAP_KEY = "backBitmap";

    boolean isProfileReady;
    //endregion

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        isProfileReady = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("profileReady", false);

        Toast.makeText(this, "profileReady : " + isProfileReady, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setContentView(R.layout.wizard_layout);
        go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);

        if (isProfileReady) {
            /*bundle.getParcelable("frontBitmap");
            bundle.getParcelable("backBitmap");*/
            currentPage = 4;
            go.setText("Home");
            summaryFragment = new SummaryFragment();
            summaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_layout, summaryFragment).commit();
        } else {
            wizOne = new WizardOne();
            if (savedInstanceState == null)
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_layout, wizOne).commit();
        }

        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isProfileReady) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    nextFragment();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void nextFragment() {

        switch (currentPage) {

            case 1:
                if (wizOne.validate()) {
                    wizTwo = new WizardTwo();
                    changeFragment(wizTwo, R.id.activity_layout);
                    currentPage++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (wizTwo.validate()) {
                    wizThree = new WizardThree();
                    changeFragment(wizThree, R.id.activity_layout);
                    currentPage++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                if (wizThree.validate()) {
                    bundle.putParcelable("frontBitmap", wizThree.getFrontBitmap());
                    bundle.putParcelable("backBitmap", wizThree.getBackBitmap());
                    summaryFragment = new SummaryFragment();
                    summaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    go.setText("Home");
                    changeFragment(summaryFragment, R.id.activity_layout);
                    currentPage++;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                passImages();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }


    public void changeFragment(ValidateFragment f, int resource) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(resource, f);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public Bitmap getFrontBitmap() {
        return frontBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBackBitmap() {
        return backBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (currentPage > 1) {
            currentPage--;
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Bundle passImages() {
        bundle.getParcelable("frontBitmap");
        bundle.getParcelable("backBitmap");
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

WizardThree.java

```
public class WizardThree extends ValidateFragment {

    Button photos, deleteFirst, deleteSecond, button;
    TextView frontText, backText, textView;
    ImageView frontPhoto, backPhoto, imageView;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    String path;
    File photo = null;
    Uri photoURI_1, photoURI_2, uri, uriOut;

    private Bitmap frontBitmap, backBitmap;

    public WizardThree() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wizard_three, container, false);
        photos = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.photos);
        photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent capture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (capture.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    try {
                        photo = createImgFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("No,", " non funziona");
                    }
                    if (photo != null) {
                        uriOut = FileProvider.getUriForFile(WizardThree.this.getContext(), "com.example.android.fileprovider", photo);
                        capture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriOut);
                        startActivityForResult(capture, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        frontText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frontText);
        frontPhoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.frontPhoto);
        deleteFirst = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteFirst);
        deleteFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deletePhoto(frontPhoto, frontText, deleteFirst);
            }
        });
        backText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.backText);
        backPhoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.backPhoto);
        deleteSecond = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteSecond);
        deleteSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deletePhoto(backPhoto, backText, deleteSecond);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (frontPhoto.getDrawable() == null) {
                photoURI_1 = uriOut;
                frontBitmap = putPhoto(frontPhoto, frontText, deleteFirst, photoURI_1);
                checkButton();
            } else if (backPhoto.getDrawable() == null) {
                photoURI_2 = uriOut;
                backBitmap = putPhoto(backPhoto, backText, deleteSecond, photoURI_2);
                checkButton();
            }
        }
    }

    //region getBitmaps
    public Bitmap getFrontBitmap() {
        return frontBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBackBitmap() {
        return backBitmap;
    }
    //endregion

    public Bitmap putPhoto(ImageView imageView, TextView textView, Button button, Uri uri) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() / 3, bitmap.getHeight() / 3, true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void checkButton() {
        if ((frontPhoto.getDrawable() != null) && (backPhoto.getDrawable() != null)) {
            photos.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            photos.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private File createImgFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imgName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storage = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File img = File.createTempFile(imgName, ".jpg", storage);
        path = img.getAbsolutePath();
        return img;
    }

    public void deletePhoto(ImageView imageView, TextView text, Button btn) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        checkButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate() {
        if ((frontPhoto.getDrawable() == null) || (backPhoto.getDrawable() == null)) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Both photos are necessary", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
```

SummaryFragment.java

```
public class SummaryFragment extends ValidateFragment {

    //region Variables
    TextView getFName, getLName, getFisCode, getBirth, getCity, getProv, getZip, getCC, getIban, getMail;
    ImageView imgOne, imgTwo;
    String strFName, strLName, strFisCode, strBirth, strCity, strZip, strProv, strCC, strIban, strMail, path;
    SharedPreferences wizardPrefs;
    private Bitmap frontBitmap = null;
    private Bitmap backBitmap = null;
    Uri uri;
    Images callBack;
    //endregion

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        frontBitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("frontBitmap");
        backBitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("backBitmap");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_layout, container, false);

        //region findViewById
        getFName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getFName);
        getLName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getLName);
        getFisCode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getFisCode);
        getBirth = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getBirth);
        getCity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getCity);
        getProv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getProv);
        getZip = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getZip);
        getCC = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getCC);
        getIban = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getIban);
        getMail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.getMail);
        imgOne = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgOne);
        imgTwo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgTwo);
        //endregion

        wizardPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("USERDATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        getFName.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("Nome utente", strFName));
        getLName.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("Cognome utente", strLName));
        getFisCode.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("Codice Fiscale", strFisCode));
        getBirth.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("Data di nascita", strBirth));
        getCity.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("Città", strCity));
        getZip.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("CAP", strZip));
        getProv.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("Provincia", strProv));
        getCC.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("CC", strCC));
        getIban.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("IBAN", strIban));
        getMail.setText(wizardPrefs.getString("E-mail", strMail));
        imgOne.setImageBitmap(frontBitmap);
        imgTwo.setImageBitmap(backBitmap);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate() {
        return false;
    }

    public Bitmap getFrontBitmap() {
        return frontBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBackBitmap() {
        return backBitmap;
    }

    public interface Images {
        Bundle passImages();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            callBack = (Images) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException c) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "Exception thrown");
        }

    }

}
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Can anyone help me figuring it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shared preference from the fragment,then in the activity just read from. This way this is no tight coupling between fragments and activities.

read from here nice example.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You already have your `onActivityResult`, so :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        isProfileReady = true;
        String imageOne = data.getStringExtra("imageOne");
    }
}
```

From your SummaryFragment you need to do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.putExtra("ImageOne", imageOne);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

finish();
```

Comment: But, correct me if I'm wrong, I can't use `setResult` method inside of anything that is not an activity.. 
On the other hand, by not using it, I get a `NullPointerException` at  `data.getStringExtra()` , am I right?

Comment: @FrensisR You should be able to do `this.getActivity().setResult(...);`